# Single, small change to SSIS package results in many changes to package XML

Tags: xml, svn, ssis

I have an SSIS package under SVN source control. I open the package in VS2010 and make a small change to a single expression in a Derived Column Data Flow Component. I click OK and then save the package (it takes a few seconds to save, which seems odd since I only made a small change). When I check the package's .dtsx file for changes, TortoiseMerge reports a TON of changes to the file. I want to see the small change I made to the expression, but it has been effectively hidden among all the other changes that were made.

Is there a way to prevent Visual Studio from making these extra changes to the package when I save it?

Upon inspecting the changes in more detail, I see VersionBuild and VersionGUID were updated, which makes sense according to [this](http://bidn.com/Blogs/userid/10/ssis-package-versions). Other than this though, it seems like the extra changes are all just a result of a reorganization of certain XML elements. In other words, the package content is the same before and after the save (except for the version and expression changes), but the organization of the content has changed.

Edit: It seems that the act of opening the package is causing this rearrangement of the XML. After opening the package for the first time, I open any Task/Data Flow Component, click OK, then save the package. This causes the package XML to be rearranged. However, if I keep the package open and repeat these steps, only the version information changes. Going further, if I close the package, re-open it, and perform these steps again, the XML gets reorganized.

Comment: So the package was originally created with a tool other than Visual Studio, and now you've opened it and saved it in Visual Studio for the first time?   If so, then the amount of changes sounds perfectly normal to me.

Comment: No, the package was created with Visual Studio. I'll edit the question to be more clear.